# Fallout Shelter save files location on Windows 10

Tags: fallout-shelter

How do you find the fallout shelter vault save file on windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

The save game files for Fallout Shelter for Windows 10 can be found in

`%appdata%\Local\Packages\BethesdaSoftworks.FalloutShelter_3275kfvn8vcwc\SystemAppData\wgs\LONG_ENCRYPTED_CODE\ANOTHER_LONG_ENCRYPTED_CODE\your saves here`

Common errors:

- If you cannot see hidden files, go onto the '*View*' tab within the Explorer, and tick '*Hidden items*'.
- If you cannot go into the packages folder, firstly right-click and go into '*Properties*'. Then go under the security tab and click '*Edit*' by the '*To change permissions, click Edit*' text. You then have to click '*Add*' after the pop-up comes up. In the text box, type your email address tied with your windows 10 account and click on '*Check names*', if it is correct, it will allow you to continue into the folder after clicking '*Okay*'.

Answer (score 0):

Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\FalloutShelter\`

- Open the File Explorer
- Paste `%LOCALAPPDATA%\FalloutShelter\`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Steam Play Linux: `<Steam-folder>/steamapps/compatdata/588430/pfx/`